# How to create a given number of rows in Oracle, based on some row, but change some fields?

Tags: sql, oracle

My task is to make copies of some string, but at the same time, the values of some fields should be different.

```sql
create table card_table (
    id number,
    card varchar(255),
    ipAddress varchar(255),
    inserted timestamp,
    lastModified timestamp

);


create sequence card_table_seq;


insert into card_table (id, card, ipAddress, inserted, lastModified)
values (CT_REQUESTS_SEQ.nextval,
        '578374998w98ewecdf',
        '235.10.12.1',
        (sysdate + interval '2' minute),
        sysdate
        );
```

These should be the resulting rows, only the fields id, inserted and last_modified differ.

[image]

To begin with, I tried like this :

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE name(countRequests IN NUMBER,  cardN IN VARCHAR2)
    IS

    ipAddress    varchar2(255);
    requestID    NUMBER;
    dateInserted Timestamp;

BEGIN
    SELECT id
    into requestID
    FROM (
             SELECT id
             FROM REQUESTS
             WHERE card = cardN
             ORDER BY inserted DESC)
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('requestID : ' || requestID);

    SELECT IP
    into ipAddress
    FROM (
             SELECT IP
             FROM REQUESTS
             WHERE card = cardN
             ORDER BY inserted DESC)
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ip Address : ' || ipAddress);

    dateInserted := (sysdate + interval '2' minute);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('dateInserted : ' || dateInserted);

    FOR counter IN 1 .. countRequests
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('counter : ' || counter);

            insert into LOGIN_BY_CARD_REQUESTS (id, card, IP, INSERTED,
                                                LAST_MODIFIED)
            select  some_seq.nextval,
                   card,
                   IP,
                   (sysdate + interval '2' minute),
                   sysdate
            from REQUESTS
            where number = cardN
              and IP = ipAddress;

        END LOOP;
END;
```

However, in one iteration I got a complete copy of all the records that are in the table. For example, there are 100 records in the table, 200 of them in 2 iterations. However, this is not the behavior I expected.

There should be 2 iterations and 2 new copies.

I decided to try this example.

```sql
create table apples
(
    ID       NUMBER,
    name     VARCHAR2(50),
    color    VARCHAR2(50),
    quantity int
);
```

```sql
INSERT into cpil.APPLES (id, NAME, COLOR, QUANTITY)
select 1 + LEVEL - 1, 'antonovka', 'green', 1
from DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

It doesn't fit either.

Then I inserted a new record and decided to make a duplicate based on it.

```sql
DECLARE

    nameCopy     varchar(255);
    colorCopy    varchar(255);
    quantityCopy int;

BEGIN

    SELECT name
    into nameCopy
    FROM (
             SELECT name
             FROM apples
             WHERE name = 'antonovka'
         )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('nameCopy : ' || nameCopy);

    SELECT color
    into colorCopy
    FROM (
             SELECT color
             FROM apples
             WHERE name = 'antonovka'
         )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('colorCopy : ' || colorCopy);


    SELECT quantity
    into quantityCopy
    FROM (
             SELECT quantity
             FROM apples
             WHERE name = 'antonovka'
         )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('quantityCopy : ' || quantityCopy);

    FOR counter IN 1 .. 5 LOOP

       quantityCopy := quantityCopy + 1;

        INSERT INTO CPIL.apples (id, name, color, quantity)
        VALUES (apples_SEQ.nextval, nameCopy, colorCopy, quantityCopy);

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('counter : ' || counter);

    END LOOP ;
end;
```

However, this method is cumbersome, since there are more fields in the real table.

Who has any ideas how to make it easier using

insert into ... select ...

or using something else ?

After all, I need to change only 2 or 3 fields, the rest need to be copied from a record that is already in the database. In addition, there is no primary key in the id field in the table. This also needs to be taken into account.

Comment: OK, you posted code you aren't satisfied with. Could you also post sample source table and the way target table should look like (based on that source)?

Comment: @Littlefoot the message shows the table and what the result should be.